# using XSLT stylesheet on XML and deformatting html

Tags: xml, xslt

i would like to create a data feed that has the basic elements of RSS 2.0 and looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"> 
<channel> 
<title>Clot3333333tory</title> 
<description>Clot333333333333333holesale pricing and bulk ordering to consumers and businesses.</description> 
<item>  
<title>
<description>
<link>
```

i am using an XSLT stylesheet on an XML document to populate this template, a problem a have run into is i want to use a tag called `<Caption>` in the XML document for the tag `<description>` in the finished project.  This 'Caption' field is formatted in html, i would like to pull the Caption data into 'description' but just display it as text and drop all the html tags. What would it look like in the stylesheet to do this?

EDIT:
the incoming XML file looks like so(including only one 'item' element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE StoreExport SYSTEM "http://store.yahoo.com/doc/dtd/StoreExport.dtd">  
<StoreExport>
<Settings>
<Published timestamp="1297187196"/>
<Locale code="C" name="English" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>  
<StoreName>Clo3333333nd.com</StoreName>
<Currency>USD</Currency>  
<ShipMethods>
  <ShipMethod>Ground</ShipMethod>
  <ShipMethod>Two Day Delivery</ShipMethod>
  <ShipMethod>One Day Delivery</ShipMethod>
  <ShipMethod>3 Day</ShipMethod>

</ShipMethods>
<PayMethods>
  <PayMethod>American Express</PayMethod>
  <PayMethod>Discover</PayMethod>
  <PayMethod>MasterCard</PayMethod>
  <PayMethod>Visa</PayMethod>
  <PayMethod>Diner's Club</PayMethod>
</PayMethods>
</Settings>
<Products>
<Product Id="agfasu">
  <Code>3616a</Code>
  <Description>Ageless Fashion Suit</Description>
  <Url>http://www.clo333333nd.com/agfasu.html</Url>
  <Thumb>&lt;img border=0 width=50 height=70 src=http://ep.yimg.33333333333st-27703333333618_2144_317652924&gt;</Thumb>
  <Picture>&lt;img border=0 width=600 height=845 src=http://ep.yimg.com/33333333-2770333333333317019111&gt;</Picture>

  <Orderable>YES</Orderable>
  <Taxable>YES</Taxable>
  <Pricing>
    <BasePrice>178.00</BasePrice>
    <LocalizedBasePrice>178.00</LocalizedBasePrice>
    <OrigPrice>299.99</OrigPrice>

    <LocalizedOrigPrice>299.99</LocalizedOrigPrice>
    <SalePrice>178.00</SalePrice>
    <LocalizedSalePrice>178.00</LocalizedSalePrice>
  </Pricing>
  <Path>
    <ProductRef Id="wochsu" Url="http://www.cl333333333333hsu.html">Womens Church Suits</ProductRef>
    <ProductRef Id="2454" Url="http://www.clo333333333nd.com/2454.html">Aussie Austine Spring/Summer 2011</ProductRef>

  </Path>
  <Availability>Usually ships the next business day.</Availability>
  <Caption>&lt;head&gt; &lt;meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language"&gt; &lt;style type="text/css"&gt; .style3 {  font-family: arial, helvetica;  font-size: medium;  font-weight: bold; } .style4 {  font-size: small; } &lt;/style&gt; &lt;/head&gt;  &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Wholesale Women&amp;#39;s Church Suits&amp;nbsp; - 3 Piece Suit - Jacket/Vest/Long  Skirt&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Aussie Austine Spring/Summer 2011&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p class="style4"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Wholesale Clothing Distributors - Church Attire, Gospel Fashion, Mother of Bride Style  at a Wholesale Price. For all your fancy, classic, elegant parties and or  occasions. Our suits come in a variety of styles to accommodate your fashion  taste. Suits for all women, moms, grandma&amp;#39;s, daughters and aunts. That classic  look that will bring attention. From stylish skirts, pants, jackets  and vests. Two piece suits, available hats and purses. Brand Name Wholesale  Ladies Apparel. &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;3&lt;strong&gt; Piece Suit - Jacket/Vest/Long Skirt&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Sizes&amp;nbsp; 8 10 12 14 16 18 20&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Color&amp;nbsp; Khaki Red&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Available Accessories: Hat and Purse&amp;nbsp; &lt;/p&gt; &lt;font face="arial, helvetica" size="4"&gt; &lt;p align="left"&gt;Orders of 12 and 24 Items are Mixed Colors and Sizes. For more  information Please call Us @ 323333300&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p align="left"&gt;Please feel free to call if you would like wholesale pricing for  larger orders&amp;nbsp;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;font face="arial, helvetica" size="2"&gt; &lt;p align="left"&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;font size="4"&gt;Please call or E-mail &lt;a href="mailto:Sal333333sland.com"&gt;Sales@cloth333333333and.com&lt;/a&gt; If you  are interested in purchasing larger quantities&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/font&gt; &lt;p align="left" class="style3"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p align="left"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p align="left"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;  &lt;p align="left"&gt;`&lt;/p&gt;</Caption>
```

you can see the 'Caption' tag i mentioned at the bottom.
i have never used xslt before, so i currently only have a skeleton that i can only get to just basically repeat all the data, even if i use 'match' templates, all of the text is included in the final product regardless.  i know i am just wording the template incorrectly, but i can find this concept explained anywhere. the wording i am using for match is:

```
<xsl:template match="Description"
<title>
<apply-template/>
</title>
</xsl:template>
```

with the intention of turning the 'Description' tag into a 'title' field in a final xml rss2.0 document

EDIT:
okay, i am using XSLTPalette and the screen has 3 output modes: 'raw','pretty','rendered' results.  when i use the stylesheet i have now to strip elements from the 'Caption' nodes, they appear like i want in the 'raw' results, it is just the text without all the escaped chars. also appears fine in the rendered result, but my data is still unstructured in the rendered result. it doesnt appear at all in the 'pretty' output box, but 'raw' is getting closer to what i need, i guess. here is an incomplete stylesheet for an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="//Product/Caption">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

two things: this effectively strips the correct section of nodes, but how would i also encapsulate the output of this section into a tag called 'description' for the final document, and what am i not doing to have only the things i want show up in the product, like to include nothing except what i specify i want.

Comment: Show the incoming XML example and the current XSLT you are using, thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide the real XML document? Right now the context of the `<Caption>` element is just one long string -- there is no HTML markup there, because it is escaped and flattened to ordinary text. I guess that you did this in an attempt to get the HTML display ...

Comment: @Dimitre: my mistake, it does look like that actually, not being in html. i glanced at it and thought it was formatted for a browser, but the '&gt' and '&lt' are to put characters in a URL or for use with http? i guess i just need the text to appear as a simple, un-styled string. that is how the XML document appears, does it look like the correct type of format to be able to even do this?

Comment: @bboyreason: Then you are out of luck. The accepted solution does not help in the general case, because it deletes everything surrounded by two escaped characters -- and it may happen that the text contains a `<` and a `>` (both escaped) that surround normal text (not a tag name). In this case the accepted solution will incorrectly delete all the surrounded text. There is no XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 solytion for such severely flattened markup. One need to use an extension function and parse the string  -- if possible to form an XML document out of it (that restores the markup). Then XSLT can do it

Comment: @Dimitre: i see, but i can use similar syntax to strip maybe other portions of the string? like below commenter said, 'like regexp', do you think if i left an escaped " ' " or &amp, in the string it would mess up the final document, the item i need is not in "<>" so i think i can use the syntax below, but maybe just add another rule or two to strip what remains.

Comment: @bboyreason: No, in general you cannot know what escaped characters may happen in the text and whether or not they are the surrounding characters of a tag.

Comment: can i ask how you would get the output of, say, the below stylesheet piece to 'be' the necessary 'description' tag in an RSS 2.0 XML document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing exactly what you get as input, I can only suggest that you pass the nodes you want to strip HTML from, through this XSLT template.

```
<xsl:template name="strip-tags">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Just include it in you existing XSLT, applying it to the relevant `<Caption>` node.

Comment: thanks for the help, i am just learning how to use this process. just one question, would this template be within the template i use to extract the 'Caption' node? like open and close this template before final close of extracting Caption node.  what exactly that looks like, i am not sure, but one step closer

Comment: @bboy - in XSLT you can add `template` nodes to you XSLT and then use them to process specific nodes of your incoming XML. You can add `match="\\Product\Caption` to the template element, to get all Product->Caption nodes. There are other ways to use templates too (apply-template) ... but if all this is mysterious incantation to you I strongly recommend against using it without understanding how XSLT works, 'cargo-culting' should always be avoided.

Comment: cool, i understand it sort of, like 'match' will 'activate' each element that matches the string following '=' but now i see the '\' used to denote parent relationship i guess, but that is confusing because i dont see '\' used much versus '/' to denote structure. how do you make that output be tagged 'description' in the output file? i looked up 'cargo-cult' and i am not trying to do that, i was redirected here from 'superuser' this is just the most complex point i have come to with software, but i have the intention of learning the underlying concepts as i have up until this point

Comment: Oops, just noticed I put `match="\\Product\Caption"` in my other comment, when it should've been `match="//Product/Caption"`, sorry about that. By the way I didn't mean to imply you intended to use this stuff without understanding it, I was just urging against that.

Comment: @Slomojo: Do note that this answer is incomplete without **warning that this is pretty much like parsing with RegExp**. Built-in proper parsing will be added in [XPath 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml)

Comment: all of the material i find is about using xslt to turn an xml into a website, con someone just point me to something to read about making an rss2.0 like the format at top of page. everything i search about rss2.0 is just about converting from that, not to it